# is it possible to customize the display of local notification for iPhone?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am using local notification for my iphone "sayings" app.Each day(11 53 am) a saying from my app should be notified to the user.Here my problem is,i dint get any proper references for using userinfo property,so i tried to do this in another way.i used an integer variable which is increemented each time ,when app gets notification,but that too s not working fine ,local notification is showing the same sayings everyday ..please help me to solve this...
This is my code.....

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;

NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate =

[calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit )        fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[componentsForReferenceDate setDay:11] ;
[componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:6] ;
[componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2013] ;

NSDate *referenceDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForReferenceDate] ;

// set components for time 7:00 a.m.

NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate =

[calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit|   NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate: referenceDate];

[componentsForFireDate setHour:11] ;
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:53] ;
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];

// Create the notification

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
DataHandler *obj=[[DataHandler alloc] init];

notification.fireDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];//fireDateOfNotification    ;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
notification.alertBody = [obj.proverb objectAtIndex:sectionindex];//[objz[NSString   stringWithFormat: @"അകലത്തെ ബന്ധുവിനേക്കാൾ അരികത്തെ ശത്രു നല്ലത് ."] ;
notification.alertAction = @"go back";
notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"] forKey:@"information"];
notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit ;
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;


}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
DataHandler *obj=[[DataHandler alloc] init];
static int i=0;
NSLog(@"hai");
UILabel *label=[UILabel alloc];
UILabel *label1=[UILabel alloc];


label.text=[obj.explanation objectAtIndex:i];
label1.text=[obj.proverb objectAtIndex:i];
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:label1.text
                                                  message:label.text
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
i++;
sectionindex++;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can customize only the action button(hasAction = NO). You cannot do any thing with the text displayed. If the text length is more it will display the part of the text only.

I think the part of the text `As happy as a clam at high water," is a very common.....` is enough. If the user want to see the full text, **allow the user to open the app and display it there**

Comment: my app contains a list of sayings.is it possible to show the same sayings which is noified to the user...i heard that by clicking that local notification ..i can only invoke my app...

Comment: When the app is open by the notification `applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification` will get called. From there you can do anything in your app, display a view controller contain the saying is enough in your case. Make use of __userInfo__ property of the notification to set an id for the saying, when receiving notification getback the info do accordingly

Comment: here instead of a view controller i created an alertview for displaying the sayings..but didnt get any idea about getting the index of local notification

Comment: check `notification.userInfo` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In your **applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification** , include an **UIAlertView** and the full text display as an alert.